# Samba share for user groups with Ubuntu. A user can't access files created by other users

Tags: linux, samba, nfs, access-control-list, cifs

I have a folder mounted by using NFS on the server. That folder has subdirectories, and I want to share specific folders to specific user groups by using SAMBA.

It doesn't work as expected, because every user can create files, but then they can only access their own files, and not the files from others.

The NFS mount on the Samba server:

```
172.16.54.56:/export/proyectos on /proyectos type nfs (rw,noatime,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,acregmin=10,acl,nfsvers=3,addr=172.16.54.56)
```

There's only one folder right now:

```
drwsrws---+ 22 root proyecto-innovacion 3,9K 2012-08-30 11:40 innovacion
```

And then, there's files from both users:

```
-rw-rwxr--+  1 jorge.suarez  proyecto-innovacion     0 2012-08-30 12:10 Archivo de Prueba
-rw-rwx---+  1 maria.tenorio proyecto-innovacion   42K 2012-07-30 11:55 correos.xlsx
```

That '+' is because of an ACL, setted to set proper permissions to new files, so they can always be accessed to the groups. This is the only ACL I'm using on the NFS server:

```
 # setfacl -d -m mask:007 /export/proyectos
```

In fact, both users can access each other files by using NFS.

If I understand ok the output from this command, both users are mapped ok to the Samba groups, just in case.

```
# net user info jorge.suarez
Enter root's password:
Domain Users         
proyecto-innovacion  
# net user info maria.tenorio
Enter root's password:
Domain Users         
proyecto-innovacion
```

Here's the smb.conf. I also have a `homes` section but I've omitted it:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    netbios name = SAMBASRV
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8, eth0
    passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://10.1.176.237"
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    ldap admin dn = "cn=Directory Manager"
    ldap group suffix = ou=Groups,ou=CITIUS
    ldap suffix = dc=inv,dc=usc,dc=es
    ldap ssl = no
    ldap user suffix = ou=People,ou=CITIUS
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    hosts allow = 172.16.54., 127.
    hosts deny = all
    strict locking = No
[innovacion]
    comment = Proyecto innovacion
    path = /proyectos/%S
    valid users = @proyecto-innovacion
    read only = No
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    browseable = No
    browsable = No
```

To summarize the problem, the user that creates the file can access his own file. But no the others' files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give up using ACLs via NFS. The mask is not working properly.

I use inotify now instead, with a little script launched at startup:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Directory name as argument. You MUST set it also down there before using it!

LOGFILE="/tmp/inotify-log.tmp"

inotifywait -mrq -e attrib,moved_to,create --format %w%f "$1" | while read FILE ; do
    # Ignore root FIXME you have to put here all possible root arguments
    if [ -d "$FILE" ] && [ $FILE == "/export/proyectos" ] || [ $FILE == "/export/proyectos/" ] ; then
        continue;
    fi
    # Get new permissions
    PERMISOS=$(stat -c %a "$FILE")
    if [ -d "$FILE" ] ; then
        if [ $PERMISOS -ne 2771 ] ; then
            NUEVOSPERMISOS=2771

        else
            NUEVOSPERMISOS=0
        fi
    else
        # Get permissions
        if [ ${#PERMISOS} -eq 3 ] ; then
            PERMISOS_ADICIONALES=0
            PERMISOS_USUARIO=${PERMISOS:0:1}
            PERMISOS_GRUPO=${PERMISOS:1:1}
            PERMISOS_OTROS=${PERMISOS:2:1}
        else
            PERMISOS_ADICIONALES=${PERMISOS:0:1}
            PERMISOS_USUARIO=${PERMISOS:1:1}
            PERMISOS_GRUPO=${PERMISOS:2:1}
            PERMISOS_OTROS=${PERMISOS:3:1}
        fi

        # Check permissions
        if [ $PERMISOS_USUARIO -ne $PERMISOS_GRUPO ] || [ 0 -ne $PERMISOS_OTROS ] ; then
            NUEVOSPERMISOS=${PERMISOS_ADICIONALES}${PERMISOS_USUARIO}${PERMISOS_USUARIO}0
        else
            NUEVOSPERMISOS=0
        fi

    fi

    # Set permissions
    if [ $NUEVOSPERMISOS -ne 0 ] ; then
        chmod $NUEVOSPERMISOS "$FILE"
                # Debug output
                OUTPUT="$(date) : $FILE ($PERMISOS -> $NUEVOSPERMISOS)"
                echo $OUTPUT >> $LOGFILE
    fi

done
```

The permissions are fixed now by this script, instead of fall back into ACLs via NFS.